# X11 Include Issues With c++ Via CLion On FreeBSD 11?

Tags: cmake, x11, clion

I'm using CMake on FreeBSD 11 within CLion and have the following CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(owm)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp owm.cpp owm.h)
add_executable(owm ${SOURCE_FILES})
set(LIBS ${LIBS})
find_package(X11 REQUIRED)
if (X11_FOUND)
    include_directories(${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})
    link_libraries(${X11_LIBRARIES})
endif(X11_FOUND)
file(GLOB MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS
    "test/*"
)
file(COPY ${MY_PUBLIC_HEADERS} DESTINATION test)
```

Which seems to work fine, however when going to compile the project I get the following:

```
/usr/local/bin/cmake --build /home/cory/projects/owm/cmake-build-debug --target all -- -j 12
Scanning dependencies of target owm
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/owm.dir/owm.cpp.o
[ 66%] Linking CXX executable owm
CMakeFiles/owm.dir/owm.cpp.o: In function `owm::Create(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)':
/home/cory/projects/owm/owm.cpp:20: undefined reference to `XOpenDisplay'
/home/cory/projects/owm/owm.cpp:22: undefined reference to `XDisplayName'
CMakeFiles/owm.dir/owm.cpp.o: In function `owm::owm(_XDisplay*)':
/home/cory/projects/owm/owm.cpp:31: undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
/home/cory/projects/owm/owm.cpp:32: undefined reference to `XInternAtom'
CMakeFiles/owm.dir/owm.cpp.o: In function `owm::~owm()':
/home/cory/projects/owm/owm.cpp:37: undefined reference to `XCloseDisplay'
c++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/owm.dir/build.make:121: owm] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:68: CMakeFiles/owm.dir/all] Error 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I'm not certain if this is relevant but `message(FATAL_ERROR ${X11_LIBRARIES})` returns:

/usr/local/lib/libSM.so/usr/local/lib/libICE.so/usr/local/lib/libX11.so/usr/local/lib/libXext.so

And `message(FATAL_ERROR ${X11_INCLUDE_DIR})` returns:

```
/usr/local/include
```

Within the offending file I have:

```
#include "owm.h"
extern "C" {
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
}
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename T>
T* CHECK_NOTNULL(T* t) {
    if (t == NULL) {

    }
    return (t);
}

std::unique_ptr<owm> owm::Create(const std::string& display_str) {
    const char* display_c_str = (display_str.empty() ? nullptr : display_str.c_str());
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(display_c_str);
    if (display == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to open X display " << XDisplayName(display_c_str);
        return (nullptr);
    }
    return (std::unique_ptr<owm>(new owm(display)));
}

owm::owm(Display *display)
        : _display(CHECK_NOTNULL(display)),
          _root(DefaultRootWindow(_display)),
          WM_PROTOCOLS(XInternAtom(_display, "WM_PROTOCOLS", false)),
          WM_DELETE_WINDOW(XInternAtom(_display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", false)) {

}

owm::~owm() {
    XCloseDisplay(_display);
}

void owm::Run() {

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command `link_libraries` affects only on **futher** executables/libraries. From [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/link_libraries.html):

> Specify libraries or flags to use when linking any targets created later in the current directory or below by commands such as `add_executable()` or `add_library()`.

So you need to either:

- use `link_libraries` **before** `add_executable` or
- use `target_link_libraries` instead (this is preferred way)

Comment: Thank you so much, that was driving me nuts.

Comment: Simple pattern about ordering CMake commands, affecting on executable created: If command accepts **target** parameter, it should come **after** `add_executable()` call; otherwise command should come **before** that call.